# zfs: How to create pool of two existing vdevs, then mount it

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zfs

I have two pools (shortened output from zpool status):

```
  pool: vol1
    vol1
      mirror-0
        ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ004702
        ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ069805
  pool: vol2
    vol2
      mirror-0
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S300MZ7G
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S300ELBZ
```

I want to combine them into one pool, call it "Aquilonde", then mount that on my server in the filesystem as /plex-server. I'm new at zfs. Have googled without much satisfaction. I tried this and variations of it:

```
~# zpool create Aquilonde vol1 vol2
cannot open 'vol1': no such device in /dev
must be a full path or shorthand device name
```

Answer (score 2):

I waver between answering or deleting this question. The question was naive: I was misled by an article on the topic. Here is the sequence of commands that resulted in the solution to my question. Included is also the name mapping that's useful to know about if you don't already.

```
$ zpool create aquilonde mirror /dev/sda /dev/sdb  # create pool aquilonde and first mirror
$ zpool add aquilonde mirror /dev/sdd /dev/sde     # add second mirror to pool
$ zpool export aquilonde                           # fix up naming
$ zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id aquilonde        # ibid
$ zpool status                                     # examine status--all's well
  pool: aquilonde
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:
        NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        aquilonde                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
       mirror-0                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
         ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ004702  ONLINE       0     0     0
         ata-WDC_WD20EARX-00PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ069805  ONLINE       0     0     0
       mirror-1                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
         ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S300MZ7G           ONLINE       0     0     0
         ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_S300ELBZ           ONLINE       0     0     0
$ zfs set mountpoint=/plex-server aquilonde        # set up /plex-server in host filesystem
```

The mistake I made was thinking that I had to build from the ground up. This works perfectly now. Hope it helps someone else.